# SSIS excel destination - Import column in ascending order

Tags: sql, ssis

I have a working SSIS that imports data from a view into a excel destination (.xls file - it has to be this format).

The view in SQL management studio shows the data ordered by the column I want as I have an **Order By**.

But when it imports into excel via the SSIS the sort is lost.

Is it possible to load the data in as it looks in the view.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Why not use the sort transformation to order the data?

Comment: Thanks. I'll give that a try.

Answer (score 0):

You can either use the Sort Transformation to order the data in the dataflow, or you can use a query for your Source component, and include an ORDER BY in your query.  If you do the latter, you should go the Advanced properties of the Source Component, and set the IsSorted property, and the SortKeyPosition property of the column that the results are sorted on.

Comment: Excellent.  Thank you for this.  So simple!

Comment: Glad it helped, please close the question by clicking the check-mark to the left of this answer.   Thanks!